# 'image' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Here is the error:

```
'image' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Any help in understanding what is happening and how to fix it would be much appreciated.

Basically I have a 'Partner' model with a one to many relationship to a 'Product' model. I am using inlineFormSet for the 'Product' model which has fields like partner, image, desc, price etc.

The form displays correctly in admin and when the form is rendered but upon submitting it throws the error.

here is my views.py

```
def partner_create(request):
#Trying to add multiple product functionality
    if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
        raise Http404

    ProductFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Partner, Product, form=ProductForm, extra=3)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        partnerForm = PartnerForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        formset = ProductFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, queryset=Product.objects.none())

        if partnerForm.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():

            instance = partnerForm.save(commit=False)
            instance.save()


            for form in formset.cleaned_data:
                image = form['image']
                product = Product(partner=instance, image=image)
                product.save()
            messages.success(request, "Partner Successfully Created")
        else:
            print partnerForm.errors, formset.errors
    else:
        partnerForm = PartnerForm()
        formset = ProductFormSet(queryset=Product.objects.none())
    return render(request, "partner_form.html", {"partnerForm": partnerForm, "formset": formset})
```

here is my models.py

```
class Partner(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location, 
        null=True, 
        blank=True, 
        width_field="width_field", 
        height_field="height_field")
    banner_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location,
        null=True, 
        blank=True, 
        width_field="width_field", 
        height_field="height_field")
    mission = models.TextField()
    vision = models.TextField()
    height_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    width_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    # text = models.TextField()
    website_link = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    fb_link = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    twitter_link = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    ig_link = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("partners:detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
        # return "/partner/%s/" %(self.id)

    def get_markdown(self):
        mission = self.mission
        markdown_text = markdown(mission)
        return mark_safe(markdown_text)


#Creating a many to one relationship so that one can upload many Products
class Product(models.Model):
    partner = models.ForeignKey(Partner, default=None)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    product_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location,
    # product_image = models.ImageField(upload_to= (upload_location + '/' + name), Something like this need to append actual product name so these dont just get dumped in the media for partners
        null=True, 
        blank=True, 
        width_field="width_field", 
        height_field="height_field",
        verbose_name='Image',)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    height_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    width_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name
```

here is my forms.py

```
class PartnerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    mission = forms.CharField(widget=PagedownWidget(show_preview=False))
    vision = forms.CharField(widget=PagedownWidget(show_preview=False))
    # publish = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget)
    class Meta:
        model = Partner
        fields = [
            "name",
            "logo",
            "banner_image",
            "mission",
            "vision",
            "website_link",
            "fb_link",
            "twitter_link",
            "ig_link",
        ]

class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    image = forms.ImageField(label='Image')
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            "partner",
            "image",
            "description",
            "price"
        ]
```

I understand that the problem is with this line in the views.py

```
product = Product(partner=instance, image=image)
```

But I do not understand why what I have done doesn't work "image=image" (i have seen it done like this before) or where to go from here. Thanks in advance

Full Traceback:

```
File "...lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "...blog/src/partners/views.py" in partner_create
  49.               product = Product(partner=instance, image=image)

File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in __init__
  443.                 raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % list(kwargs)[0])

Exception Type: TypeError at /partners/create/
Exception Value: 'image' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misspelling the field name as it is not `image` but `product_image`. Change the following line:

```
product = Product(partner=instance, image=image)
```

to

```
product = Product(partner=instance, product_image=image)
```